# Play framework - Set default language on server side

Tags: java, playframework, locale

In my Play application I have an independent job which runs on server side in background. That job uses messages from `messages.pl`, but the problem is the server's default language is English so my messages cannot be reached. How can I change global default language for my application?

I have already tried `Lang.apply("pl")` in my Global class, but it doesn't work. I have also tested `Controller.changeLang("pl")` at user request, but since my job doesn't depends on any request it doesn't work as well.

Of course my `application.conf` file contains `application.langs="pl"`.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mension, I'm using Play Framework 2.3.9.

Here is the code where I'm using messages (last line of each `catch` block). This function is called from the job (Akka scheduler):

```
public String processText(String text, String LPMN) {
    lastError = "";

    try {
        String idt = nlpTextUpload(text);
        return process(idt, LPMN);
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SerelServiceRs.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Text to process is empty", ex);
        play.Logger.warn("Text to process is empty", ex);
        lastError = lastError.concat(Messages.get("error.process.emptyText")).concat("\n");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SerelService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Problems in processing LPMN", ex);
        play.Logger.error("Problems in processing LPMN", ex);
        lastError = lastError.concat(Messages.get("error.process.lpmnProblem")).concat("\n");
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SerelService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        play.Logger.error("Processing interrupt", ex);
        lastError = lastError.concat(Messages.get("error.process.interrupt")).concat("\n");
    }
    return "";
}
```

And here is text from `messages.pl`:

```
error.process.emptyText=[BŁĄD]: Tekst do przetworzenia jest pusty
error.process.fileNotFound=[BŁĄD]: Plik nie został prawidłowo wczytany
error.process.lpmnProblem=[BŁĄD]: Błąd podczas wywoływania Web Serwisu
error.process.interrupt=[BŁĄD]: Przetwarzanie zostało przerwane
```

Comment: Which version of Play are you using? In Play 2.4 you should set `play.i18n.langs = [ "pl" ]`.

Comment: Also can you show the code of the Job?

Comment: Just make sure that your preferred language comes first in supported lang list, e.g. `play.i18n.langs = [ "pl", "en" ]`